# More space efficient than bitmap

Tags: data-structures, bitmap

Do you have any suggestions for a data structure that occupies less space than the bitmap index for storing document ids? I have tried to illustrate how the data looks like. For each key (1,2,3,…., 100), you will have a set as a value.

I have tried to think in terms of the inverted index. But I read that bitmap is more space efficient. I have seen various works on bitmap but, I was wondering if there is any work besides that.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure

Comment: @MattTimmermans thank you once again. I have looked up regarding succinct data structure. Some how, I am not clear where can values be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classical answer to your question is the [Elias-Fano structure](https://glowacka.org/lectures/ir/DATA20021-Lecture3-web.pdf). It is within half a bit per item of optimal, and does well on short lists like you have.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Now, i need to find a proper compression method with which I can perform join operation between multiple lists as fast possible.

Comment: Elias-Fano works find for joins.

Comment: you are absolutely right. It took me long to understand but I see that particularly for small list, the state of the art compression algorithms not necessarily compress well.